# Unit tests creation/automation for Worklight apps

Tags: unit-testing, ibm-mobilefirst

Does worklight 6.2 support any frameworks for enabling automation of unit tests execution of worklight hybrid/native mobile apps as part of the continuous integration?

Whenever a developer checks in a code, we have continuous integration already setup that would build and create an  Android apk file with the latest changes. As a next step, we want to write set of unit tests that need to be configured for auto execution post the checkin and build process is completed on the machine (preferably in Java runtime environment without the need of launching an emulator/device for test execution).

I have gone through Mobile Test Workbench that comes with Worklight, but this addresses more of functional testing automation but not unit testing.

Any assistance here pls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no officially supported framework for unit tests for Worklight apps.

That said, anything that works with web apps could potentially be used for this purpose. You can read the following IBM Worklight blog post about this exact topic: [Unit test your JavaScript code in IBM Worklight hybrid applications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/unit_test_your_javascript_code_in_ibm_worklight_hybrid_applications?lang=en).

The author uses the QUnit unit testing framework library, and PhantomJS for the test execution, as well as Maven as a way to integrate to a continuous test execution environment.

Comment: Thanks Idan for your response. I will check the link. But do you suggest to use two separate frameworks for unit testing the native as well as the web components?

Comment: My pleasure. If this helped solve your question, please mark as answered.

Comment: Sure Idan. One quick thing - do you suggest to use two separate frameworks for unit testing the native as well as the web components in a hybrid scenario?

Comment: If you have a lot of custom native code that changes a lot and you feel testing will be beneficial, you could probably use Xcode's built-in tools for this.